# React Native Maps and callout with images

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-maps

I am not able to display **images** (both from the assets and web) in custom marker callout : the image in callout is always shown as a blank rectangle.

```
class CustomCalloutView extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (

            <View>
                <View>
                    <Text style={{
                        fontWeight: "bold",
                    }}>
                        Test
                </Text>
                </View>
                <View>
                    <Image
                        source={{ uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/logo-og.png' }}
                        style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}
                    />
                </View>
            </View>

        )
    }
}
```

And the main Map component is:

```
<MapView
    style={{ flex: 1 }}
    initialRegion={{
        latitude: 37.78825,
        longitude: -122.4324,
        latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
    }}>
    {this.state.markers.map(marker => (
        <Marker
            key={marker.id}
            coordinate={marker.latlng}>
            <Callout>
                <CustomCalloutView />
            </Callout>
        </Marker>
    ))}
</MapView>);
```

The marker is correctly shown, and the callout renders, but the image is not shown. The same image works if i use it in a normal view.

I am using expo (expo.io) but also tried emulator and installed APK on the device (android; no info about ios).

Comment: Try adding `resizeMode: "cover"` to your image style and see if it works.

Comment: Does not work :/

Comment: are you using the latest maps version?

Comment: "expo": "^32.0.0"

"react": "16.5.0"

"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz"

"react-native-maps": "^0.23.0"

Comment: Does it work with a local static image?

Comment: No, no images are shown in custom callouts.

Comment: This is a known bug with react-native-maps. There is a long-standing issue thread on the repo discussing it

Comment: Have a look, there are a few workarounds: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/issues/1870

Comment: Ok, there's nothing to do, other than switching to WebView in the Callout. This also causes differences in visual rendering between iOS and Android, but still ...

Answer (score 8):

Use Image inside Text component.
Something like this:

```
<Text>
      <Image style={{ height: 100, width:100 }} source={{ ... }} resizeMode="cover" />
</Text>
```

Another workaround by using WebView.
I think is the proper solution for this right now.

```
<View>
      <WebView style={{ height: 100 , width: 230, }} source={{ uri: ... }} />
</View>
```

Answer (score 2):

Positioning the `<Image/>` was a bit challenge in the custom `Callout` for `Android`. It's a bit mystery for `Android`, IMHO. Especially, with [the trick to display it by wrapping around Text](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/2633#issuecomment-524324731). Looks like, it affects the styling, too. I've had to figure out monotonously the https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#resizemode with this "fix" along with some custom styling what works, pff.

I've ended up with 2 different styles, one for `Android`, one for `iOS`.

```
{Platform.OS === "android" ? <Text style={styles.imageWrapperAndroid}>
  <Image
    resizeMode="cover"
    source={
      event.imageUrl
        ? { uri: event.imageUrl }
        : require("../assets/images/no-image.jpeg")
      }
    style={styles.imageAndroid}
  />
</Text> : <Image
  source={
    event.imageUrl
      ? { uri: event.imageUrl }
      : require("../assets/images/no-image.jpeg")
    }
  style={styles.imageIOS}
/>}
...
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
imageAndroid: {
  height: 200,
  width: 330,
},
imageIOS: {
  height: "50%",
  width: "100%",
},
imageWrapperAndroid: {
  height: 200,
  flex: 1,
  marginTop: -85,
  width: 330,
},
...
});
```