# The image displayed in marker callout is cut

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps, react-native-image

In my app, I want to display callout on a user clicks on the marker. I read that there are problems with displaying images in callout and a lot of people suggest placing the image in `<Text>` component [[1](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/issues/2633#issuecomment-524324731),[2](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/issues/431#issuecomment-524321467),[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54436503/react-native-maps-and-callout-with-images). For smaller images/icons this solution  works, but I want to display one more "bigger" image, and here is an effect:

[image]

I don't know why this image has this "top margin" and why it is cut in the half. I was trying a lot of changes in the style of this `Image` and it's `resizeMode` but nothing is working. My other images in callout - like this icon on the bottom - had the same problem but adding a bigger size to the  component in which there are placed help and everything looks fine. I was trying this solution on this big top image but it isn't working.

I will be grateful for any help and suggestions.

He is the Callout component code:

```
import { Dimensions, Image, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { colors } from '../constants/Colors'

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('screen')

function getSpotDifficulty(spot) {
  switch (spot.difficulty) {
  case 0:
    return 'DLA KAŻDEGO'
  case 1:
    return 'UMIARKOWANA'
  case 2:
    return 'DUŻA'
  case 3:
    return 'TYLKO DLA PROSÓW'
  default:
    return ' - '
  }
}

function getSpotPopularity(spot) {
  switch (spot.popularity) {
  case 0:
    return 'MALE'
  case 1:
    return 'SREDNIE'
  case 2:
    return 'DUŻE'
  default:
    return ' - '
  }
}

const WATER_TYPE_FLAT_IC = require('../assets/images/ic_flat.png')
const WATER_TYPE_WAVE_IC = require('../assets/images/ic_wave.png')

const DIFFICULTY_EASY_IC = require('../assets/images/ic_flag_white_24.png')
const DIFFICULTY_HARD_IC = require('../assets/images/ic_flag_red_24.png')
export default class SpotMarkerCallout extends Component {
  render() {
    const marker = this.props.marker
    const waterTypeIcon = marker.waterType === 0 ? WATER_TYPE_FLAT_IC : WATER_TYPE_WAVE_IC
    const difficultyIcon = marker.waterType === 0 ? DIFFICULTY_EASY_IC : DIFFICULTY_HARD_IC
    return (
      <View style={styles.markerCallout}>
        <Text >
          <Image style={{flex: 1, height: 200}}
                 resizeMode={'cover'}
                 source={require('../assets/images/example_spot_photo.jpg')}/>
        </Text>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <View style={styles.markerHeader}>
            <Text style={styles.spotNameText}>
              {marker.name}
            </Text>
            <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
              <View style={styles.sportsIconsContainer}>
                <View style={styles.singleInfo}>
                  <Text style={styles.textViewForIcon}>
                    <Image style={styles.sportIcon}
                           source={marker.windsurfing ? require('../assets/images/windsurfing_icon.png') : null}/>
                  </Text>
                </View>
                <Text style={styles.textViewForIcon}>
                  <Image style={styles.sportIcon}
                         source={marker.kitesurfing ? require('../assets/images/kitesurfing_icon.png') : null}/>
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.textViewForIcon}>
                  <Image style={styles.sportIcon}
                         source={marker.surfing ? require('../assets/images/surfing_icon.png') : null}/>
                </Text>
              </View>
              <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}>
                <View style={[styles.singleInfo, { marginRight: 8 }]}>
                  <FontAwesome name="star" color={colors.ratingColor} size={10}/>
                  <Text style={{ marginRight: 4, color: colors.ratingColor }}>{marker.rating}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={[styles.singleInfo, { marginRight: 8 }]}>
                  <FontAwesome name="location-arrow" color={colors.secondaryColor} size={10}/>
                  <Text style={{ marginRight: 4, color: colors.secondaryColor }}>{marker.distance} km</Text>
                </View>
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
          <Text style={styles.descriptionText} numberOfLines={3} ellipsizeMode='tail'>
            {marker.description}
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', marginVertical: 8 }}>
          <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', marginLeft: 4, }}>
            <View style={styles.singleInfo}>
              <Text style={styles.infoIconTextView}>
                <Image style={styles.infoIcon} source={waterTypeIcon}/>
              </Text>
              <Text style={styles.infoText}>{marker.waterType === 0 ? 'FLAT' : 'WAVE'}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.singleInfo}>
              <Text style={styles.infoIconTextView}>
                <Image style={styles.infoIcon} source={require('../assets/images/ic_shaka_128.png')}/>
              </Text>
              <Text style={styles.infoText}>{marker.schools ? ' SZKOLENIA DOSTĘPNE' : 'BRAK SZKOLEN'}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', marginLeft: 16, }}>
            <View style={styles.singleInfo}>
              <Text style={styles.infoIconTextView}>
                <Image style={styles.infoIcon} source={difficultyIcon}/>
              </Text>
              <Text style={styles.infoText}>{getSpotDifficulty(marker)}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.singleInfo}>
              <Text style={styles.infoIconTextView}>
                <Image style={styles.infoIcon} source={require('../assets/images/ic_peoples.png')}/>
              </Text>
              <Text style={styles.infoText}>{getSpotPopularity(marker)}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

SpotMarkerCallout.propTypes = {
  marker: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  markerCallout: {
    flex: 1,
    width: width * 0.8,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    paddingLeft: 12,
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
  },
  markerHeader: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  spotNameText: {
    fontSize: 22,
    fontFamily: 'dosis_light',
    textTransform: 'uppercase',
    alignSelf: 'center',
  },
  sportsIconsContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginRight: 8,
  },
  singleInfo: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  infoIcon: {
    height: 18,
    width: 18,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  infoIconTextView: {
    height: 24,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  descriptionText: {
    fontSize: 12,
    color: colors.textBlackSecondaryColor,
    paddingTop: 5,
  },
  sportIcon: {
    height: 24,
    width: 24,
  },
  textViewForIcon: {
    height: 32,
  },
  infoText: {
    fontSize: 10,
    paddingLeft: 8,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'center',
  },
})
```

And here is the code of usage:

```
      <MapView.Callout onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SpotInfo', { chosenSpot: spot })}>
    <TouchableHighlight>
      <SpotMarkerCallout
        marker={spot}/>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  </MapView.Callout>
</Marker>
```

Comment: Pro tip: używaj angielskiej terminologii do programowania :)

Answer (score 0):

i have notices you are using  component change that to view
like

`const newWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width`

`<View style={{ width: newWidth * 0.18, height: newWidth * 0.18 }}>
<Image style={{ width: newWidth * 0.18, height: newWidth * 0.18 }} source={require('your image path')} />
</View>`

newWidth * 0.18 is the 18% width is the screen, change 0.18 to your desired percentage